# Averages of $L(s,\chi)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Let $(\frac{m}{n})$ denote the usual quadratic Jacobi symbol.
What is the
abscissa of convergence
of the double Dirichlet series ?
$$
\sum_{\substack{m,n \in \mathbb{N} \\ \gcd(m,n)=1 \\m,n\equiv 1 \mod{4}}}
\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)(mn)^{-s}
$$

Comment: In what sense is convergence intended?  That is how do $m$ and $n$ go to infinity?

Comment: I do not mind about this at all. I guess $M\leq M,n\leq N$ and $M,N \to \infty$ looks natural but if one can get a smaller abscissa for $m,n\leq x,x \to \infty$ or perhaps $mn\leq x,x \to \infty$ then I would also be happy with this.